# Java item event mouse click

Tags: java, combobox

I have to handle an event in a combobox when the user click the item (not when the combobox change the state).

I have four combobox:
(1Combo: Parent category) 
(2 Combo: The sons of the category 1)
(3 Combo: the sons of the category 2) 
(4 combo: the sons of the category 3)

Each one calls the list to add the items for the other one (the sons of the category choosed).

But my problem is that I have an itemstatechange event and I want to know if the item has been clicked NOT if the combo changes state.

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource()==jComboBoxCategorias1) {
        handleEventCombo1();
    }
    if (e.getSource()==jComboBoxCategorias2) {
       handleEventCombo2();
    } 
    if (e.getSource()==jComboBoxCategorias3) {
        handleEventCombo3();
    }
    if (e.getSource()==jComboBoxCategorias4) {
        handleEventCombo4();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a mouse listener to the combobox and implement the mouseClicked method.

```
comboBox.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println(comboBox.getSelectedItem());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that `comboBox` is actually a container. So if you really want to have all the mouse events you should add the listener to all the components it contains.

```
public void addMouseListener(final MouseListener mouseListener) {
    this.comboBox.addMouseListener(mouseListener);

    final Component[] components = this.comboBox.getComponents();
    for(final Component component : components) {
      component.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
    }

    this.comboBox.getEditor().getEditorComponent().addMouseListener(mouseListener);
  }
```

Please visit [swing mouse listeners being intercepted by child components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091531/swing-mouse-listeners-being-intercepted-by-child-components) for more details.